# 1980s sci-fi British schools TV show with noseless aliens

Tags: story-identification, tv, soft-sci-fi, educational

When I was a kid, more than 30 years ago, I remember watching a TV show at school in the UK. Would have been mid-to-late '80s. I think it was probably part of an English language thing, where they'd have worksheets for the kids to do after watching the show.

In this TV show, there were aliens who masqueraded as humans. Sometimes they'd revert to their alien form and I think they were bald, and definitely had no noses. I remember the poor cast members were wearing prosthetics that blocked their ability to breathe normally, and ended up delivering their dialogue sounding terribly nasal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @hfuy Good question, and I have some possible answers for you but if you can provide a bit more detail it would help. Can you say if this was a BBC or ITV production? And are you definetly sure it was part of schools programming or an after schools show. It it was after school the description of the aliens seems to match "Aliens in the Family" from 1987 on the BBC. you can see the aliens in this Youtube clip at the 9 minute mark. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-zsyAGw4aw

Comment: I wonder if you are confusing elements of The Boy From Space which appeared on Look and read in 1980 with Aliens in the Family?

Comment: "Aliens in the family" - that's it. Cracking, thanks!